# How to download the entire webpage

Tags: c#, c++, windows-mobile, winapi, compact-framework

Is there any sample application source which download the entire web-page in windows mobile..
I mean,in desktop when i do save as,entire webpgae gets saved.Same way  i want it to be in windows mobile..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

No, I can't provide sample code, but 
I guess you'd have to parse the HTML file for included other files and download these as well. 
As you're only talking about images, I'd try to following for a start:

1. Download HTML file
2. Look for `<img>` tags and parse these for the picture file name
3. For all the picture file names: download these as well

Please note that this does not yet include background images through CSS.

Comment: Or images loaded via Javascript. That could be _really_ ugly.

Comment: Didn't mention JavaScript on purpose. CSS could be ugly to parse, but JS would be a pain... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to download the mobile-version of a webpage, use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) and set the agent string to a mobile device, such as the following:

```
Opera/9.50 (J2ME/MIDP; Opera Mini/4.0.10031/298; U; en)
```

If you are trying to save the content of a page to your mobile device for offline browsing, you'll need to scrape the page yourself.  There are some libraries out there for dealing with HTML in C# (like [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)), but I'm not sure if they are compatible with the compact framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the source code anymore but in the past I have used libcurl for Windows mobile, it is quite easy to use it to download anything http and ftp and of course 'src's of , and  and href of .

Comment: what is libcurl.. were i get it...
how to use